# Не создается свой анализатор elasticserch через python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Не сохраняется settings когда создаю индекс в elasticsearch при помощи  API python.
Когда я делаю тоже и самое через postman, то все сохраняется корректно.

```
elastic_client.indices.create(index="products", body=MAPPING_FOR_TEST)

MAPPING_FOR_TEST = {
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "rus_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "rus_analyzer_filter",
                        "synonym_filter"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "rus_analyzer_filter": {
                    "type": "hunspell",
                    "locale": "ru_RU",
                    "dedup": True
                },
                "synonym_filter": {
                    "type": "synonym_graph",
                    "synonyms": ["говяжий, говядина"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "rus_analyzer",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В результате маппинг создается, но все, что связанно с settings не проходит

Вот вывод:

```
{
    "products": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "routing": {
                    "allocation": {
                        "include": {
                            "_tier_preference": "data_content"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "provided_name": "products",
                "creation_date": "1675599906237",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "3ii5DafjQJOIHiI_ISYRpQ",
                "version": {
                    "created": "8020399"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуйте `elastic_client.indices.create(index="products", mappings={"properties": ...}, settings={"index": ...}`

Comment: Я так пробовал, все равно не выходит
Может дело в самом словаре?

Comment: Добавьте в пост конкретные значения для этого случая, пожалуйста? По идее, если через postman всё верно создаётся, то сами параметры должны быть правильными.

Comment: Я решил проблему тем, что изменил клиент с AsyncElasticsearch на обычный. Получается, что сам индекс создаю через Elasticsearch, а вся остальное уже через асинхронный. Возможно это костыли, но работает

Comment: Похоже на баг в библиотеке, AsyncElasticsearch.indices должен быть ровно такой же, как Elasticsearch.indices. Впрочем... пробовали смотреть, что асинхронный возвращает? Такое ощущение, что результирующий индекс получается из дефолтного шаблона (там тоже text + keyword), полностью игнорируя всё, что вы туда передаёте.